# Trying to use AMPScript within the JOIN/STOP message, results in the message "There was an error processing your message"

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, mobileconnect, marketing-cloud-connect

EDIT:

I moved all of this code into a CloudPage accepting _MobileNumber as a query string parameter, and replaced the Mobile Connect AMPScript with an HTTPGet call to the CloudPage.  Same issue.

END EDIT

I have the normal, typical JOIN and STOP messages set up in Mobile Connect. What I'd like to do is edit the JOIN message to include AMPScript to update the Salesforce CRM contact record by the mobile number. I tested the AMPScript within a CloudPage and it works as expected. When I add the AMPScript into the JOIN message, I get the message "There was an error processing your message".

Here's the JOIN message:

```
%%[
    set @sfrs = RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Contact','Id,FirstName,Phone','Phone','=',_MobileNumber) 
    for @i = 1 to RowCount(@sfrs) do 
       set @row = Row(@sfrs,@i) 
       UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('Contact',Field(@row,'Id'),'ConsentToTexts__c','True') 
       UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('Contact',Field(@row,'Id'),'PreferredCommunicationMethod__c','Mobile Phone') 
    next @i
]%%
    You're now subscribed to XXXXXXXXX Notifications. For more info, email XXXX@abc.gov or visit ABC.info/SMS.Msg may freq may vary. Msg & Data Rates May Apply. Reply STOP to cancel.
```

Is there anything I might be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

Turns out that the Salesforce documentation is outdated!  I had to use MOBILE_NUMBER and not _MobileNumber in the SMS message.  Now it works!

For those interested in the solution:

Whenever a subscriber texts STOP, the response message contains code to update ConsentToTexts__c to FALSE and PreferredCommunicationMethod__c to “Email”, for all Contact records associated with the mobile number that initiated the STOP message.  Whenever a subscriber texts JOIN, the response message also contains code to update ConsentToTexts__c to TRUE and PreferredCommunicationMethod__c to “Mobile Phone” for all Contact records associated with the mobile number that initiated the JOIN message.

In addition, I added a data extension to capture all JOIN and STOP messages simply for debugging purposes in case we need to go back to resolve any issues around this.  The fields I added to this table that get populated are Mobile Number, CreatedDate (current date/time), SFRowCount (this is just the count of Contact records that match the mobile number), and Message which is either STOP or JOIN.

The issue I was experiencing before was the result of Salesforce documentation inconsistency.  Documentation mentioned I should use _MobileNumber as the variable to pass through to my code, when in fact it needed to be MOBILE_NUMBER.

Instead of writing the AMPScript code within the SMS message itself, I created a CloudPage in SFMC.  The SMS message makes an HTTPGet call to the CloudPage URL and passes in MOBILE_NUMBER.  Then, the CloudPage does its thing.

**Here’s the JOIN keyword message:**
[image]

**Here’s the CloudPage code that corresponds to the URL in the message above:**

```
%%[
  set @phone1 = RequestParameter('mobile')
  set @phoneTemp = Substring(@phone1,2,Length(@phone1))
  set @phone = Format(@phoneTemp,"(###) ###-####")
  set @sfrs = RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Contact','Id,FirstName,Phone','Phone','=',@phone)
  set @rowCount = RowCount(@sfrs)
  InsertData('MobileConnectTesting','MobileNumber',@phone,'SFRowCount',@rowCount,'Message','JOIN')
  
  if RowCount(@sfrs) > 0 then
    for @i = 1 to RowCount(@sfrs) do
      set @row = Row(@sfrs,@i)
      UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('Contact',Field(@row,'Id'),'ConsentToTexts__c','True')
      UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('Contact',Field(@row,'Id'),'PreferredCommunicationMethod__c','Mobile Phone')
    next @i
  endif
]%%
```

Notice I had to format the mobile number as (###) ###-####.  It natively came through as 12223334444.  This resulted in not being able to match on any Contact records.

The same process is followed for the STOP keyword message.  I created a separate CloudPage URL for capturing the STOP request (I could have created just one CloudPage to be honest) and the code looks almost identical except that it updates the ConsentToTexts__c to FALSE and PreferredCommunicationMethod__c to “Email”.